# Call a PHP function from the command line

Tags: php, function, command-line-interface

I have a file called address.php with a few functions in it. I want to call a specific function in that file from the command line. How?

The name of the function is called exportAddress and that function expects a single parameter.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

By using the `-r` parameter you can run a script in-line.

`php -r "require 'address.php'; exportAddress(12345);"`

There are no other options. A function in PHP can only be called by a PHP script.

Comment: php --run "require 'address.php'; exportAddress(12345);" which is easy to remember to call from CLI

Comment: @Tarik what could you do if the parameter you need to pass in is an Oracle Database Connection which is the output from another function?

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
php  -r 'include  "/var/www/test/address.php";exportAddress(1);'
```

where  `"/var/www/test/arr.php"` is the file name, including path, and `exportAddress()` is a function inside that file.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to the top of the file "/var/www/test/address.php"...

```
foreach ($argv as $i=>$arg )
{
    if ( $arg == "exportAddress" )
    { 
        exportAddress($argv[$i+1]);
    }
}
```

Then from the command line, execute:

```
php /var/www/test/address.php exportAddress 12345
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make your file "somefile.php" organized as follows:

```
function func1(){....}
function func2(){....}
function func3(){....}
....
foreach ($argv AS $arg){
    function_exists($arg) AND call_user_func($arg);
}
```

Then from the command line or a Linux cronjob, you run the following command:

```
php /path/to/somefile.php arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.1.0 (7.1.0 on windows) PHP can be executed from the shell by running

```
php -a
```

This starts PHP's interactive shell. More info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php).

With PHP's shell, running you can require files the same way you would from a file.

So if the previous command was run from the folder containing the file:

```
php > require 'myFile.php';
```

If it is in a subfolder:

```
php > require 'path/to/file/myFile.php';
```

Then execute any function defined in myFile.php.

```
php > myFunction(myParamsIfAny);
```

I guess you can use any variable defined in the same file or require any other file containing the variables needed, although I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Samer Ata and Simon Rodan's answers, you can use the following to be able to execute any function with any amount of arguments:

```
if(isset($argv[1]) && function_exists($argv[1])) {
  $parameters = array_slice($argv, 2);
  call_user_func($argv[1], ...$parameters);
}
```

This is done by removing the script and function name from `$argv` and then using the spread operator (`...`) to interpret each element in the array as an argument to `call_user_func`.

The operator is supported from PHP 5.6 onward (and 5.5 can do some of the things using functions). You can read more about it in [the official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).
For completeness, this is also known as argument unpacking.

Answer (score 0):

Note that using `php -r` assumes php-cli is the binary that got installed as ‘php’. If php -v shows the ‘php’ is php-cgi, type `/path/to/php/bin/php-cli -r` instead. In case it’s not there, you’ll have to re-compile with cli enabled.

The doc has relevant pages on this.

Answer (score -1):

for call a specific function in a PHP file from the command line by using -r:

php -r 'include "address.php"; exportAddress("value");'

tip: "value" is the actual value that you want to pass to the exportAddress function.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why did you copy-pasted the solution already offered in other answers?