# execute a function with exec php

Tags: php, exec, execute

I need to execute a function using exec command in php. I have this:
exec("php ./myfile.php >> ./log.txt &");

But I want to execute an specific function "myFunction" in myfile.php

How could I do this?

```
<?php
    class A {
        exec("php ./myfile.php >> ./log.txt &");
    }
?>
```

myfile.php

```
<?php
    class B {

        function myFunction(){
            ....
        }

        function otherFunction(){
            ....
        }
    }
?>
```

I need to throw several functions as a parallel processes

Comment: import that file and call the function? =/

Comment: execute a php file inside a php file? `We need to go deeper`

Comment: why you need it with exec? include the file, and call it may better

Comment: Look into PHP's  INCLUDE, REQUIRE, INCLUDE_ONCE and REQUIRE_ONCE functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a php function from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761915/call-a-php-function-from-the-command-line)